# не работает слайдшоу на cайте joomla3

Tags: joomla, mootools

Сайт был обновлен до версии joomla3.7
Скорее всего именно после этого действия перестало отображаться слайдшоу RokGallery.

Очевидно что проблема с mootools, на как именно это исправить?
В консоли выдает целую серию ошибок:

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined
at js-5181af5ac30576ec7814964f59d42289.php:148
at js-5181af5ac30576ec7814964f59d42289.php:156
jquery-migrate.min.js:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
thesite.org/:94 Uncaught ReferenceError: RokGallery is not defined
at http://thesite.org/en/:94:29
at http://thesite.org/media/system/js/mootools-core.js?
39402a02a69b119494320eeb02e60a6a:121:21
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function.forEach (http://thesite.org/media/system/js/mootools-core.js?
39402a02a69b119494320eeb02e60a6a:5:460)
at Array.each (http://thesite.org/media/system/js/mootools-core.js?
39402a02a69b119494320eeb02e60a6a:9:303)
at fireEvent (http://thesite.org/media/system/js/mootools-core.js?
39402a02a69b119494320eeb02e60a6a:120:501)
at HTMLDocument.j (http://thesite.org/media/system/js/mootools-core.js?
39402a02a69b119494320eeb02e60a6a:175:218)
thesite.org/:106 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 
'scrollerContainer' of undefined
at thesite.org/:106
at i (mootools-core.js:118)
at m (mootools-core.js:119)
Navigated to http://thesite.org/en/navigation-2
js-5181af5….php:148 Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined
at js-5181af5….php:148
at js-5181af5….php:156
(anonymous) @ js-5181af5….php:148
(anonymous) @ js-5181af5….php:156
jquery-migrate.min.js:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
navigation-2:91 Uncaught ReferenceError: RokGallery is not defined
at http://thesite.org/en/navigation-2:91:29
at http://thesite.org/media/system/js/mootools-core.js?
39402a02a69b119494320eeb02e60a6a:121:21
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function.forEach (http://thesite.org/media/system/js/mootools-core.js?
39402a02a69b119494320eeb02e60a6a:5:460)
at Array.each (http://thesite.org/media/system/js/mootools-core.js?
39402a02a69b119494320eeb02e60a6a:9:303)
at fireEvent (http://thesite.org/media/system/js/mootools-core.js?
39402a02a69b119494320eeb02e60a6a:120:501)
at HTMLDocument.j (http://thesite.org/media/system/js/mootools-core.js?
39402a02a69b119494320eeb02e60a6a:175:218)
(anonymous) @ navigation-2:91
(anonymous) @ mootools-core.js?39402a0…:121
(anonymous) @ mootools-core.js?39402a0…:5
each @ mootools-core.js?39402a0…:9
fireEvent @ mootools-core.js?39402a0…:120
j @ mootools-core.js?39402a0…:175
navigation-2:103 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 
'scrollerContainer' of undefined
at navigation-2:103
at i (mootools-core.js?39402a0…:118)
at m (mootools-core.js?39402a0…:119)
(anonymous) @ navigation-2:103
i @ mootools-core.js?39402a0…:118
m @ mootools-core.js?39402a0…:119
Navigated to http://thesite.org/en/
js-5181af5….php:148 Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined
at js-5181af5….php:148
at js-5181af5….php:156
(anonymous) @ js-5181af5….php:148
(anonymous) @ js-5181af5….php:156
jquery-migrate.min.js?39402a0…:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 
1.4.1
(index):94 Uncaught ReferenceError: RokGallery is not defined
at http://thesite.org/en/:94:29
at http://thesite.org/media/system/js/mootools-core.js?
39402a02a69b119494320eeb02e60a6a:121:21
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function.forEach (http://thesite.org/media/system/js/mootools-core.js?
39402a02a69b119494320eeb02e60a6a:5:460)
at Array.each (http://thesite.org/media/system/js/mootools-core.js?
39402a02a69b119494320eeb02e60a6a:9:303)
at fireEvent (http://thesite.org/media/system/js/mootools-core.js?
39402a02a69b119494320eeb02e60a6a:120:501)
at HTMLDocument.j (http://thesite.org/media/system/js/mootools-core.js?
39402a02a69b119494320eeb02e60a6a:175:218)
(anonymous) @ (index):94
(anonymous) @ mootools-core.js?39402a0…:121
(anonymous) @ mootools-core.js?39402a0…:5
each @ mootools-core.js?39402a0…:9
fireEvent @ mootools-core.js?39402a0…:120
j @ mootools-core.js?39402a0…:175
(index):106 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollerContainer' 
of undefined
at (index):106
at i (mootools-core.js?39402a0…:118)
at m (mootools-core.js?39402a0…:119)
```

Comment: трудно будет вам помочь, однако вопрос, какое отношение имеет ваш сайт с доменом http://thesite.org ??  почему JS идёт от http://thesite.org/media/system/js/mootools-core.js ?

Comment: вместо thesite должен быть домен betheltx.org

Comment: Я бы задал вопрос разработчику.

Comment: тогда непонятно почему в логах у вас другой домен? или вы не свои логи выложили тут? ))